# Control CPU over GPU performance

Tags: windows-10

I'm using a 3D Rendering app that recommends NVIDIA high performance video card.

I've build this config:

- MSI Z-390 Pro Series Motherboard
- i7 8th generation CPU from Intel
- NVIDIA Quadro M500
- 8 Gigabytes Memory ram / 64 Gigabytes Ram 3600 GHZ.

Everything is working perfectly except the 3D app. The CPU works 100% when used and the GPU 1 or 2% sometimes. It's a very low performance for this powerful graphics card.

How do I make it work in the opposite way? How can I make the processor allow the GPU processor to work with the proper performance?

Comment: That graphics card equals to a Geforce 930M which is pretty outdated by now. I don't understand what you mean by 64 GB RAM? (I didn't edit it out expecting you'll fix it)

Comment: What app are you using?

Comment: @CaldeiraG I also didn't edited it out but proposed many grammatical correction and a style improvement. The original is very poorly written. That aside, you' re correct about the graphics card.

Comment: *What app are you using?* and which version of the Nvidia drivers have you installed?

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia seems good to me, I accepted it.

Comment: You can't directly control how the CPU or GPU is used by a program unless the program itself has settings for that. If you tell us what application you are using there *might* be a solution to your problem if the application supports using the GPU for rendering at all. Otherwise, the program may just be built to do its rendering on the CPU and you would need to look for another rendering program that can use the GPU. Another possibility is that only 2% of your GPU *is needed* for the "rendering", but another function of the application is over-burdening your CPU.

Comment: Hi Guys about your comments. I want to apologize the Card it is NVIDIA M5000. The app it is digital 3d suit from Optitex. This app specialized in fashions garments 3D Rendering and the program itself doesn't have any specific set up for graphics. They minimum requirements of the software are over cover with this configuration I previously described. When I run the program the CPU its shows 100% of performance and the GPU shows only 2% performance most of the time.

Comment: The most CUDA you have the best rendering perform you get. The web research I got, it said the opposite when you do rendering numbers are GPU 100% and CPU around 40 to 60%. I will appreciate your advise in this matter. Thank you